# Add persistent attribute to live JDO class. (App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jdo

How can I add a new `@Persistent` attribute to a class that gets stored on App Engine as JDO (Similar to adding a new column to a relational live database table)? When I add a new attribute I get the exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The
>   response could not be deserialized

Answer (score 0):

Adding new property (column) into existing persistent entity **is not a problem on GAE**. I'm also using JDO and do that quite often. Existing entities won't have new property set of course. 
The problem must be in the layers above the datastore access layer.